# Whats the difference between package and groupId in maven

Tags: java, maven

I understand the terms, `groupId`, `artifactId` and `version`. While reading about `package`, I can see it is **The name of your root package. The default is the `groupId` you entered before.**.

In that case, what is the difference between `package` and `groupId`?
I guess its always the same, or if they can be different than how? Someone explain

[image]

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Seems like you are asking what does `package` means when using Maven Archetype to generate a new Maven project.

The `package` is to configure the root java package that contains all the generated source codes. So if you set the `package` to `com.foo.bar` , the generated project will contain a folder `com/foo/bar/` in `/src/main/java`.

`groupId` , together with `artifactId` and `version` is a kind of an unique identifier of your library . That means after you package your project as a JAR and publish it to the world , other developers can import it to their project to use by specifying the correct `groupId` ,  `artifactId` and `version` in their `pom.xml`.

So , the `package` is just the internal root package used by your project internally and it will not affect how developer locates and import your JAR to their project.  The `package` and the `groupId` can be different.

*(But of course, you are supposed to name the package to some unique name such that it does not conflict with other well-known libraries (e.g. don't name it as `java.lang` or `org.springframework` etc.)*

Comment: Best Answer ( I love you )